# Resultados diferentes ao usar != ou > em condição do loop

Tags: python

Estava fazendo exercícios de Python e me deparei com o seguinte problema.

Supondo que a população de um país A seja da ordem de 80000 habitantes com uma taxa anual de crescimento de 3% e que a população de B seja 200000 habitantes com uma taxa de crescimento de 1.5%. Faça um programa que calcule e escreva o número de anos necessários para que a população do país A ultrapasse ou iguale a população do país B, mantidas as taxas de crescimento. 
Então busquei resolver da seguinte forma:

A = população 1 = 80000

B = população 2 = 200000

tempo = 0

```
while A != B:
A = A + A*(0.03)
B = B + B*(0.015)
tempo = tempo + 1
else:
print(A,B,tempo)
```

Conduto, quando rodo o programa, aparece ''inf inf'' para A e B e o tempo dá um número muito grande. Achei uma solução na internet, porém não entendi porque há diferença. A solução só modifica o operador `!=` pelo operador `<`:

```
while A < B:
    A = A + A*(0.03)
    B = B + B*(0.015)
    tempo = tempo + 1
    else:
    print(A,B,tempo)
```

Eu entendo que se A for menor que B a solução também funciona. Mas por que se A for diferente de B a solução não funciona?

Comment: Por que talvez as variáveis sendo comparadas nunca cheguem a um valor exatamente igual, até porque o tipo de dados de ponto flutuante é inerentemente impreciso e não deve ser utilizado em testes de igualdade estrita.

Answer (score 4):

Modificando um pouco o seu programa, colocando o `print` dentro do `while`, podemos entender o que está acontecendo:

```
a = 80000
b = 200000
tempo = 0
while a != b:
    a += a * 0.03
    b += b * 0.015
    tempo += 1
    print(a, b, tempo)
```

Esse programa vai imprimir **muitas** linhas, mas separei essas duas em particular:

```
500032.13864656974 503413.2186819931 62
515033.10280596686 510964.41696222295 63
```

Esse é o ponto em que o valor de `a` passa a ser maior que `b` (quando `tempo` é `62`, `a` é menor, mas na iteração seguinte, ele passa a ser maior).

Por isso, se a condição for `while a < b`, ele vai parar na iteração `62` (pois na `63`, o valor de `a` será maior, fazendo com que o *loop* pare).

Mas se a condição for `while a != b`, ele não vai parar nesta iteração, porque os valores de `a` e `b` continuam sendo diferentes. E como agora `a` é maior que `b` e `a` está crescendo a uma taxa maior, os valores continuarão diferentes.
O *loop* só vai parar quando `a` e `b` forem iguais. E quando eles ficarão iguais? Nas últimas linhas do programa podemos ver:

```
inf 1.7702779365710949e+308 46852
inf 1.7968321056196613e+308 46853
inf inf 46854
```

Como pode ver, chega uma hora que os valores de `a` e `b` ultrapassam [o máximo permitido para um `float`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477332) e se tornam "infinito". Neste ponto, `a` e `b` se tornam iguais e o *loop* se encerra.

---

Um outro detalhe é que esse `else` é desnecessário. Um bloco `else` associado a um *loop* [é executado sempre que o *loop* termina sem ser interrompido por um `break`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979970), mas como nesse caso não tem `break`, ele sempre será executado. Então você pode fazer simplesmente:

```
a = 80000
b = 200000
tempo = 0
while a < b:
    a *= 1.03
    b *= 1.015
    tempo += 1

print(a, b, tempo)
```

Veja que mudei também o cálculo do aumento de `a` e `b` (se aumenta 3%, basta multiplicar por `1.03`, o mesmo vale para um aumento de 1,5%).

Answer (score 3):

A condição que você colocou `!=` ou seja `A` diferente de `B` torna o programa tendendo para o infinito. Quando se utiliza o `A < B`, a condição faz parar o programa ao ter `A` ficando igual ou sendo maior de `B`.

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma abordagem não iterativa para esse problema.

```
import math

a = 80000
b = 200000

t = math.ceil(math.log(a/b, 1.015 / 1.03))


print(a * 1.03 ** t, b * 1.015 ** t, t)
```

Teste no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/Expansaopopulacional)

Para entender, um pouco de cálculo vem a calhar.

Olhando o seu problema com atenção é possível identificar que se trata da expansão composta de dois vetores populacionais dada uma frequência temporal comum a ambos.

[image: Equação da expansão populacional]

onde:

- Pa é população inicial de A.
- Pb é população inicial de B.
- Ca é a taxa de crescimento de A.
- Cb é a taxa de crescimento de B.
- t é o tempo que leva para as duas populações se igualarem

Essa é formula de [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Bernoulli), é mesma fórmula usada para calcular juros compostos, também é usada para calcular expansão a mediante a taxa versus frequência.

Então para aproveitar essa fórmula dentro da linguagem de programação devemos isolar a incógnita `t`. Continuando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja o momento de intersecção das duas populações é dado por `math.log(a/b, 1.015 / 1.03)` e é arredondado para cima com [`ceil()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) pois o exercício pede a data em anos e para calcular cada população no período de usa-se a fórmula já apresentada `P x (1 + C) ^ T`.

Answer (score -1):

Eu não tenho certeza, mas a população de A e B nunca serão iguais além do infinito.

Por isso o EXERCÍCIO fala:  A população do país A ultrapasse OU iguale a população do país B, mantidas as taxas de crescimento.

Como não vai igualar o jeito é calcular quando vai ultrapassar

```
pop_a = 80000
pop_b = 200000
ano_passou = 0 

while pop_a < pop_b:

    ano_passou += 1
    mais_pop_a = pop_a * 3 // 100
    pop_a += mais_pop_a
    mais_pop_b = pop_b * 1.5 // 100
    pop_b += mais_pop_b

    if pop_a > pop_b and pop_a != pop_b: 
        print(f'A população da cidadade A: {pop_a:.0f} habitantes, Passa a população da cidade B: {pop_b} habitantes',end='')
        print(f', após {ano_passou} anos. Além disso, a população de B nunca será exatamente igual à população de A')
        print()
    
    elif pop_a == pop_b:
        print(f'A população da cidade A e da cidade B irão igualar-se após {ano_passou} anos')
```