# Java - Variável "x" não inicializada

Tags: java, algoritmo, lógica, java-8, programação-estruturada

estou com uma dúvida:

O código é o seguinte:

```
package yan.exercises.java.struct.repeat;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class exe2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double popA;
        double popB;
        double taxA;
        double taxB;

        boolean validate = false;

        while (validate = true) {
            System.out.print("Enter the population of city A: ");
            popA = scan.nextDouble();

            if (popA > 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Population city A need to be bigger than 0.");
            }

        }
        while (validate = true) {
            System.out.print("Enter the population of city B: ");
            popB = scan.nextDouble();

            if (popB > 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Population city B need to be bigger than 0.");
            }
        }

        while (validate = true) {
            System.out.print("Enter the growth rate of A: ");
            taxA = scan.nextDouble();

            if (taxA > 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Growth rate city A need to be bigger than 0.");
            }

        }
        while (validate = true) {
            System.out.print("Enter the growth rate of B: ");
            taxB = scan.nextDouble();

            if (taxB > 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Growth rate city B need to be bigger than 0.");
            }

        }

        int count = 0;
        while (popA < popB) {
            popA += (popA / 100) * taxA;
            popB += (popB / 100) * taxB;
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Population A: " + popA);
        System.out.println("Population B: " + popB);
        System.out.println("Years:     " + count);
    }

}
```

Está me retornando os seguintes erros:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The local variable popA may not have been initialized
    The local variable popB may not have been initialized
    .....
```

Como consigo resolver este problema?
Quando eu inicializo a variável com 0, consigo retorno, mas o programa não me retorna o resultado desejado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, isso aqui não faz sentido:

```java
boolean validate = false;
while (validate = true) {
```

Você inicializa a variável com `false`, para logo em seguida mudar seu valor para `true` (sim, o operador `=` é de atribuição, o `while` **não** está comparando se `validate` é igual a `true`). E a variável não tem seu valor alterado em lugar nenhum, então no fim ela é desnecessária: use apenas `while (true)` e pronto (até porque você usa um `break` dentro do *loop*, o que garante que em algum momento ele será interrompido).

O que acontece é que, por algum motivo o compilador não consegue detectar que ele entrará neste *loop*, e por isso ele acha que a variável não será inicializada. Se você dá um valor qualquer para elas antes do `while`, "funciona", mas se usar `while (true)` também resolve.

Mas na verdade tem muita repetição no código e dá para simplificar. Repare que a leitura dos dados é igual, só muda o nome do campo e da variável. Então daria para generalizar para um método, mais ou menos assim:

```java
static double readValue(Scanner scan, String fieldName) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.printf("Enter the %s: ", fieldName);
        double value = scan.nextDouble();
        if (value > 0) {
            return value;
        } else {
            System.out.printf("The %s must be greater than 0.\n", fieldName);
        }
    }
}
```

Aí no `main` você só faz assim:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
double popA = readValue(scan, "population of city A");
double popB = readValue(scan, "population of city B");
double taxA = readValue(scan, "growth rate of A");
double taxB = readValue(scan, "growth rate of B");
```

E para o cálculo, não precisa do *loop*, pois pode ser usada a fórmula de Bernoulli (explicada em detalhes [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/453989/112052)):

```java
double percA = 1 + (taxA / 100);
double percB = 1 + (taxB / 100);
double t = Math.ceil(Math.log(popA / popB) / Math.log(percB / percA));
System.out.println("Population A: " + popA * Math.pow(percA, t));
System.out.println("Population B: " + popB * Math.pow(percB, t));
System.out.println("Years:     " + t);
```

Claro que ainda podem ser feitas outras validações. Por exemplo, se a população de A for maior que B, já pode retornar zero sem fazer nenhum cálculo; se a população de A for menor que B, mas a taxa de crescimento de B for maior, então A nunca alcancará B, etc.

Comment: Valeu!! Eu estava realmente tentando lembrar da utilização while(true)!