# PYTHON - problema com dois salários

Tags: python, while, porcentagem

Primeiramente, existem dois indivíduos nessa questão. Carlos e João.

O Salário de João corresponde a um terço do salário de Carlos. A cada mês, o salário de Carlos recebe um aumento de 2% e o de João recebe um aumento de 5%. A questão pede para que o programa diga quantos meses são necessários para que o salário de João se iguale ao de Carlos. Eu fiz o código, ele funciona, mas retorna o resultado errado.

```py
salariocarlos = 9
salariojoao = salariocarlos / 3
meses = 0

while salariocarlos != salariojoao:
 
 salariocarlos += (salariocarlos * 0.02)
 salariojoao += (salariojoao * 0.05)
 meses += 1

print(f'foi necessário {meses} meses para que João igualasse seu salario ao de Carlos)
```

O código roda, mas o resultado sai muito errado. Com o salário de Carlos valendo apenas 9 reais o programa retorna que são necessários 35732 meses para que João iguale.

Comment: É basicamente o mesmo problema [daqui](/q/453908/112052): uma hora o salário de João fica maior que o de Carlos, mas eles não ficam necessariamente iguais. Por isso o loop continua, até que os salários atinjam o limite de um `float` e se tornam "infinito" (leia o link já indicado para entender em detalhes). A solução é trocar para `while salariocarlos > salariojoao:`

Comment: A resposta abaixo está errada, ela "funciona" em alguns casos por coincidência, mas pode falhar em outros, veja: https://ideone.com/pFuv2N - dito isso, a ideia do [pt.so] é que as respostas sejam as mais corretas possíveis e sirvam de referência para futuros visitantes. Por isso a resposta abaixo nem deveria ter sido marcada como correta, justamente por falhar em vários casos que não deveria. No link que indiquei acima tem soluções melhores

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Cara, isso me parece um problema de arredondamento, não?

Quando trabalhamos com floats, fazer um match exato assim (a == b) é complicado, ainda mais com operações no meio. Veja:

```
salariocarlos = 9
salariojoao = salariocarlos / 3
meses = 0

while round(salariocarlos, 0) != round(salariojoao, 0):
 
 salariocarlos += (salariocarlos * 0.02)
 salariojoao += (salariojoao * 0.05)
 meses += 1

print(f'foi necessário {meses} meses para que João igualasse seu salario ao de Carlos')
```

Se você arredondar pra 0 casas decimais o resultado é 38.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Arredondar "funciona" por coincidência em alguns casos, mas falha em vários outros. Ex: https://ideone.com/pFuv2N (aqui  também mostra uma opção de solução correta). Ver também [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/453908/112052) para outras soluções, que é basicamente o mesmo problema